# Unable to GetCellValue from GUIGridView in sap-gui

Tags: java, sap-gui

I have a project using [the jacob project](https://github.com/freemansoft/jacob-project) to automate SAP gui automation (version 7.70). I'm able to access a GuiGridView as an ActiveXComponent.  The subtype shows it's a GridView when I call `grid.getPropertyAsString("SubType")`. The visible row count returned is correct when I call `Dispatch.call(grid, "VisibleRowCount").toString()`.  Double clicking a cell does not error when I call `Dispatch.call(grid, "DoubleClickCurrentCell")`.  However, I'm unable to get past an error occurring when I try to get a cell value via `Dispatch.call(grid, "GetCellValue", Integer.valueOf(1), "Synchronization Object")`.  I get an error

```
com.jacob.com.ComFailException: A COM exception has been encountered:
At Invoke of: GetCellValue
Description: 80004003 / Invalid pointer
```

Trying to wrap them in an array of objects like I've seen done in the [PoojaGugu  library](https://github.com/PoojaGugu/SAP-GuiClient-Automation/blob/master/Java/library/src/main/java/com/library/generic/SAPGeneric.java#L709) I get:

```
com.jacob.com.ComFailException: A COM exception has been encountered:
At Invoke of: GetCellValue
Description: 80020005 / Type mismatch.
```

And trying to pass them in as Variants, I get:

```
At Invoke of: GetCellValue
Description: 8000000a / The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available.
```

Any suggestions about what I might be overlooking or where I'm going wrong with this?

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.  The format of

```
Dispatch.call(grid, "getCellValue", 3, "ID")
```

was correct, but I needed to use the column identifier (like ID or RL_FROM_T) rather than the column name (like "Synchronization Object" or "From Release").